# What is needed to create dwg from drawing?

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design, software

Does anyone know of an accurate method for building a dwg file from a scan of a scaled drawing or plan. The dwg files will also be referenced for or made into 3d models so pulling the information straight into a modelling software would work too if possible.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't show relevancy to 3D printing

Answer (score 3):

It's not an easy task and according to my knowledge there is no way to do it fully automatically (I might be wrong of course).

You have options as follows:

Read scans and ...

1. recreate it manually in CAD application
2. recreate it using a [digitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_tablet) (in the old days they had pucks - a kind of magnifier with crosslines to digitize from printouts/blueprints)
3. create 3D object omitting 2D drawings
4. convert bitmap to vectors in 2D app
5. use a scanning service [like this](http://www.amsimaging.com/blueprint-scanning) (would be expensive)

Depending on complexity of your schemas, the easiest way, would be option 1 or 3. Option 4 is very doubtful (even if it's the most automatic way, it won't create useful data).

The most of CAD apps have an option to import bitmaps and then work on such a "background". For example, in AutoCAD use command [Imageattach](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/beta/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-0F75E36F-6138-424C-9510-5847CE1D8852-htm.html)